# How can I add static text to all \url{} items in Latex?

Tags: url, latex

I have a bunch of `\url{}` items in my paper and I want to generate each of them automatically as follows:
`\url{https://www.asdf.com/}` -> `https://www.asdf.com/ (Last accessed in March 2022)`

How can I redefine the latex `\url{}` command to introduce this hardcoded text snippet after each url it generates?

Comment: Do all your urls have the same last accessed date?

Comment: Yes, they have the same accessed date.

Comment: I actually got as far as `\DeclareUrlCommand\url{\def\UrlRight{\textit{ (Last Accessed in March 2022)}}}`, but the URL link won't function anymore :/

Comment: Are you using the hyperref or url package? Please make a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the hyperref package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\AddToHook{cmd/url@/after}{\textit{ (Last Accessed in March 2022)}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\url{https://www.asdf.com/}

\end{document}
```